# Why does `/sbin` not included in $PATH for new user?

Tags: paths, ifconfig

`ifconfig` is located in `/sbin/ifconfig`. I don't have problem issuing `ifconfig` command in root user.

The problem started when I created a new user.

```
root@Ubuntu:~# useradd -m user
root@Ubuntu:~#

root@Ubuntu:~# passwd user
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@Ubuntu:~# 

root@Ubuntu:~# su user
user@Ubuntu:/root$ id
uid=1003(user) gid=1003(user) groups=1003(user)
user@Ubuntu:/root$
```

`ifconfig` is not found in the new user.

```
user@Ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
-su: ifconfig: command not found
user@Ubuntu:~$
```

Temporary workaround is execute it from full path `/sbin/ifconfig`

```
user@Ubuntu:~$ whereis ifconfig
ifconfig: /sbin/ifconfig /usr/share/man/man8/ifconfig.8.gz
user@Ubuntu:~$ 

user@Ubuntu:~$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
user@Ubuntu:~$
```

`ifconfig` was not found as `/sbin` is no longer configured in the new user environment.

```
user@Ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
user@Ubuntu:~$ 

user@Ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH | grep sbin
user@Ubuntu:~$
```

I don't see this issue on root user as `/sbin` is part of `$PATH` by default.

```
root@Ubuntu:~# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

root@Ubuntu:~# echo $PATH | grep sbin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
root@Ubuntu:~#
```

1. The question is why `/sbin` is not included by default? Doesn't this make things harder for user?
2. How to make sure `/sbin` is added automatically in `$PATH` instead of modifying it manually for each users?

Comment: How did you create the user? What is the output of `cat /etc/environment`?

Comment: Thanks @pa4080 for your feedback.

`useradd -m <newuser>`

.bashrc .bash_history .bash_logout .profile also been created.

`user@Ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
user@Ubuntu:~$`

Comment: Possibly the behaviour you are seeing is because (by default) `useradd` sets the user's login shell as `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash`

Comment: @steeldriver

Default shell for new user is `/bin/bash`
However I don't see this in `/etc/passwd`
user@Ubuntu:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
user@Ubuntu:~$ 

user@Ubuntu:~$ egrep 'ubuntu|user' /etc/passwd
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
user:x:1002:1002::/home/user:
user@Ubuntu:~$

Comment: @CharlotteRussell how exactly are you logging in to the root account? There appears to be a potential issue whereby `su -` and/or `su -l` does not cause `pam_env` to read `/etc/environment`. See for example [Why doesn't `su -` re-read /etc/environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292815/why-doesnt-su-re-read-etc-environment)

Answer (score 5):

The `/sbin` directory is for system maintenance and/or administrative tools. So only administrators are allowed to use it and you don't have this directory in your $PATH. You can read more in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s16.html).

The right place to add new value to `$PATH` variable are user's `~/.profile` file or system `/etc/profile` file. Usually there is already a line with `$PATH` so you need just to add `/sbin` to the start of the line. Or just add this line at the end of the file:

```
PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
```

Also you can edit `/etc/skel/.profile` file. This file will be copied to a user's home directory when you create a new one. But if you want to have this feature for all users, change `/etc/profile`.

Comment: I guess this is implied in this answer but not explicit: non-root user should not need `sbin` in their path. `sudo` will be able to find the binary; tab-completion works as well. If not then there is a bug in Ubuntu.

Comment: @FranklinYu tab completion does not work if the program is only in an `sbin` folder which is not on the PATH. How would it work ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă It works on Debian. Note that by “work” I mean that tab completion will check binaries in `sbin` only when completing commands starting with `sudo`.